# Proper way of writing a custom layer in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, keras-layer

I see at least three ways of creating custom layers in keras.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

def reset_seed(seed=313):
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    tf.random.set_seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(313)

class Method1MLP(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, in_units, out_units, **kwargs):
        self.dense = Dense(in_units)
        self.out = Dense(out_units)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def call(self, x):
        temp = self.dense(x)
        return self.out(temp)


class Method2MLP(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, in_units, out_units, **kwargs):
        self.dense = Dense(in_units)
        self.out = Dense(out_units)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def __call__(self, x):

        temp = self.dense(x)
        return self.out(temp)


class Method3MLP(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, in_units, out_units, **kwargs): 
        self.in_units = in_units
        self.out_units = out_units
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def __call__(self, x):

        temp = Dense(self.in_units)(x)
        return Dense(self.out_units)(temp)

# define dummy inputs and outputs
x = np.random.random((100, 10,5))
y = np.random.random((100, 1))
```

Now first build the model without custom layers

```
reset_seed()

inp = Input(shape=(10,5))
temp = Dense(5)(inp)
out = Dense(1)(temp)
model =  Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss='mse')
print(model.summary())

model.fit(x=x,y=y, epochs=5)
```

**Using method 1**

```py
reset_seed()

inp = Input(shape=(10,5))
out = Method1MLP(5,1)(inp)
model =  Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss='mse')
print(model.summary())

model.fit(x=x,y=y, epochs=5)
```

**Using method 2**

```
reset_seed()

inp = Input(shape=(10,5))
out = Method2MLP(5,1)(inp)
model =  Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss='mse')
print(model.summary())

model.fit(x=x,y=y, epochs=5)
```

**Using method 3**

```
reset_seed()

inp = Input(shape=(10,5))
out = Method3MLP(5,1)(inp)
model =  Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss='mse')
print(model.summary())

model.fit(x=x,y=y, epochs=5)
```

All of the above code snippets give the same results.
Although official documentation recommends method 1 but method 2 and method 3 have the advantage that they expose intermediate outputs i.e. outputs inside the custom layer. This makes it easy to get these outputs as numpy arrays after training. I also want to understand the difference between methods 2 and 3. Does it not matter whether I initiate a layer in the `__init__` method or not?

Is there any difference between method 2 (when we explicitly write `__call__` method) and method 1 (when we let keras Layer's `__call__` method to call our `call` method?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any difference in method 1 and 2. Maybe you forgot something?

I would think that method 3 is slower, as it has the additional overhead of creating the `Dense` layer every time.

Can't you just have best of both worlds, like in the snippet below?

```
class Method4MLP(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, in_units, out_units, **kwargs):
        self.dense = Dense(in_units)
        self.out = Dense(out_units)
        self.in_units = in_units
        self.out_units = out_units
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def __call__(self, x):
        temp = self.dense(x)
        return self.out(temp)
```

Answer (score -1):

To me, none of these make sense. Especially where you define a Dense layer in the `__call__` dunder method. But then, what's the purpose of subclassing an object when there are two of these objects inside the class definition? Looks like you could simply use a two layer sequential model instead.

Either way, the proper way to subclass a Keras layer is outlined in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models).

```
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf

class Linear(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=32, input_dim=32):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
        self.w = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim, units), dtype="float32"),
            trainable=True,
        )
        b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
        self.b = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=b_init(shape=(units,), dtype="float32"), trainable=True
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b
```

Comment: The examples are very simple but for case when e.g. there is a softmax inside `call` and we want to view the activations of this softmax, how can we view do that if we use `call()` instead of `__call__()?